# Website Link Problem after uploading to hosting

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web-hosting

When I'm working offline all are fine but after moved my files to the server the linking to the pages not updated properly.

ex:  When I enter my site name and check contact's link it shows contact.html and after I entering mysite.com/index.html and checked the contact's link it shows contact.php

I want to know what mistake I'm doing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Unfortunately there's not much advice can be given on the information that you've supplied _ Uploading to webhost can cause any number of issues but the first thing to double-check is that the folder and file structure on the webhost is EXACTLY the same as when you had the site working offline _ also spelling and usage of both uppercase & lowercase _ Make sure all of these are 100% correct_ then check them again _ You would be surprised how many times the upload goes wrong because of these basic steps _ Good Luck

Comment: @inputforcolor yes, the folder structure wasn't correct. cleared it. thank you so much